# Bash script to extract HTML comment into a Markdown file

Tags: html, parsing, bash, markdown

I learned Bash a million years ago. I just wrote this simple script used to get the first lot of HTML comments from a file, and spit it out in order to create a `README.md` file.

It is just. So. Ugly. I read bits and pieces over the years, and I am sure it can be improved so much...

Here we go:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=''
active='0';
cat  hot-form-validator.html | while read "line";do

  echo $line | grep '\-\->' > /dev/null
  if [ $active = '1' -a $? = '0' ];then 
    exit 0;
  fi;

  suppress=0;
  echo $line | grep '^ *@' > /dev/null
  if [ $? = '0' ];then suppress='1'; fi;


  if [ $active = '1' -a $suppress = '0' ];then echo $line;fi;

  echo $line | grep "<!--" > /dev/null
  if [ $? = '0' ];then active='1'; fi;

done
```

Questions:

- Is there a better way to do `grep` and then check `$?`?  Back in the day it was the way to go, but...
- Should `active` be a proper number rather than a string with a number? I  know, it could be anything... but having a string that can be `0` or `1` just feels wrong.
- Is there a better way to preserve spaces, rather than zapping `IFS`?
- Any more pearls of wisdom, other than quitting my (short lived) career of bash scripter?

Answer (score 3):

**A bug**

- If your html contains a backspace character e.g

  `<p>The special character \n is a way to include read line</p>`

your code interprets it a

> The special character n is a way to include read line.

to avoid this, add "-r" switch to your read line

`cat  hot-form-validator.html | while  read -r "line";do`

- You want to check if your file exists before reading it

> ```
> if [ -f $filename ]; then
> #do something
> else
> #do something
> fi
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A Bash loop is not the best approach.  If you are doing a lot of line-by-line processing, and invoking `grep` a lot, then `awk` would be a more appropriate tool.

```
awk '/<!--/ { ACTIVE = 1; next }
     /-->/  { exit }
     ACTIVE { print }' < hot-form-validator.html
```

But line-by-line processing is not an appropriate way to parse HTML.  [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html), for example, could do a proper job of extracting the first comment in an HTML file:

```
xsltproc --html first-comment.xsl hot-form-validator.html
```

… where `first-comment.xml` contains:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/"><xsl:value-of select="//comment()[1]"/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't really want turn xsltproc a requirement to generate the documentation -- especially since *I* control the contents of the starting file. But, I am SOLD on AWK! What's the best resource to learn it?

Comment: But also... what about the script in the original post? What if I really wanted to improve it?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk.html) seems good. Or, if you are a masochist, you could try to figure it all out from the man page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can get a bunch of Bash tips instantly by pasting your code on http://www.shellcheck.net/

A couple of things jump in the eye:

- Too many unnecessary `;` at the end of lines
- Instead of `grep ... > /dev/null`, it would be shorter to write `grep -q ...`
- Too many statements on a line when it would be more readable if split to multiple lines
- Instead of `cat file | while ...`, it would be better to write `while ... < file`
- Instead of `echo ... | grep ...`, it would be better to use here-strings, `grep ... <<< ...`
- Instead of `grep ...` and then checking the value of `$?` in an `if`, you could move the `grep` inside the `if`
- Quoting where it's not needed
- Not quoting where it's needed

With the above points improved:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=
active=0
while read "line"; do
  if [ $active = 1 ] && grep -q '\-\->' <<< "$line"; then 
    exit 0
  fi

  suppress=0
  grep -q '^ *@' <<< "$line" && suppress=1

  [ $active = 1 -a $suppress = 0 ] && echo $line

  grep -q "<!--" <<< "$line" && active=1    
done < hot-form-validator.html
```

I rewrote using `grep -q ... <<< ...` only for the sake of an example of using `grep` inside `if` statements.
But a better solution is to use native Bash pattern matching with `[[ ... ]]`, for example instead of:

```
  grep -q '^ *@' <<< "$line" && suppress=1
```

This is better, as it doesn't spawn a `grep` process:

```
  [[ "$line" =~ ^\ *@ ]] && suppress=1
```